# how to put USER in my CREATE method of Django Rest Framework

Tags: django-rest-framework, decorator, python-decorators

My drf view creates 1~3 items in one request.

My View:

```py
class UserInterestAPIView(ListCreateDeleteAPIView):
    queryset = UserInterest.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserInterestSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data.get("data")
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data, many=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

- ListCreateDeleteAPIView is custom view. It inherits mixins.

My serializer:

```
class UserInterestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserInterest
        fields = "__all__"
```

I tested with postman, so my post body looks like this:

```
{
    "data":[{
        "user":2,
        "interest":1,
        "sequence":4
    },{
        "user":2,
        "interest":10,
        "sequence":5
    }]
}
```

This works well but I realized that body data will not contain `user` because my team will use `login_decorator` for checking `user`. I can get "user" from `request.user`, but I don't know how to put `user` into every single items in my list from `request.data`.

I mean, post body data should be:

```
{
    "data":[{
        "interest":1,
        "sequence":4
    },{
        "interest":10,
        "sequence":5
    }]
}
```

and now I have User instance. My model needs user_id as well.
I guess user_passes_test doesn't fit for me. Is there any method or anything I can apply?

Edit: I'm thinking of using `for loop`, but I don't want to use it.

Comment: is user a required field in models? also, show your code how are you accepting list data in your views ??

Comment: @RanuVijay it's not required, but if there is no user field, that record isn't needed in DB. and just updated my view!